# DataGrid: replacing a DataGridTextColumn with DataGridTemplateColumn - how to make Binding work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid with a few DataGridTextColumns and I want to repace one with my own custom control. However I can't figure out how to bind.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entries, Mode=OneWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">      
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Path=Comment}" Width="Auto" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have replaced it with:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entries, Mode=OneWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <x:customTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Comment}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Comment}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I also tried to set a RelativeSource without any success. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Each of the rows gets the same datacontext whatever the type of column, so your problem here looks to be in your customtextbox rather than the binding. You could, by the way, do much the same with the celleditingtemplate of a datagridtextcolumn.

Comment: @Andy: I don't think it is the customTextBox, because the binding doesn't work even when I replace it with a 'normal' TextBox. I tried to set RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} in the binding which also did not help. The DataGridTextColumn doesn't seem to provide a CellEditingTemplate...

Comment: I'll try for a reproduction.

Comment: After messing around and trying different approaches with the binding I went back to the original implementation (as posted above) and this time it worked. I don't know what went wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me using a textbox instead of whatever your control is.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entries, Mode=OneWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Comment}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Comment}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
enter code here
```

MyItem is a viewmodel I happened to have in a scratch app.

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> entries = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>
    (
        new List<MyItem>
        {
             new MyItem{ IsChosen = false},
             new MyItem{ IsChosen = true },
             new MyItem{ IsChosen = true }
        }
    );
}
```

Looks like

```
public partial class MyItem : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool? isChosen;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string comment = "Some test string";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the test. However it does not work in my code that is a bit more complex and it seems my extraction from it may not contain the true source of the problem.

Comment: After messing around and trying different approaches with the binding I went back to the original implementation (as posted above) and this time it worked. I don't know what went wrong in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes the way.  Not always the complicated "hard" stuff I get stuck on.